# accessing html table elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to access the html input tag which is present inside a table inside a form as shown below. I have used the function below to access the element but I'm getting undefined in the output:

```
  function checkForm()
        {
            var  table=document.getElementById('register').getElementsByTagName('myTab');


            document.writeln(table);

        }
```

The above function returns undefined. Why, and how can it be fixed to return the input that I need?

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <HEAD>
        <META CHARSET = "utf-8">
        <TITLE>Register</TITLE>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reglog.css">
        </HEAD>

        <BODY>
        <h1 align=center>Register with our portal</h1>

        <FORM id="register" onsubmit="return checkForm();" METHOD="POST">

        <table name="myTab" border = 0 align=center>

        <tr >
        <td> Username </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td><input name="username" class=textbox type = text required></td>
        </tr>


        <tr >
        <td> Password </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td><input name="passwd" class=textbox type = password required></td>
        </tr>


        <tr >
        <td> Confirm Password </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td><input name="c_password" class=textbox type = password required></td>
        </tr>



        <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> <input class=button type = submit value = Register> </td>
        </tr>


        </table>

        </FORM>
        </BODY>
        </HTML>
```

Comment: **...ByTagName** <- it should be quite clear from the name that you're looking for elements that look like `<myTab></myTab>`. If you want to look for something with a name, it would be `getElementsByName`, and the "s" indicates that it returns more than one element, i.e. a nodeList.

Comment: Also, stop writing code like it was 1995. Remove the uppercase tagnames, and don't use `document.writeln` or inline javascript, make sure your attributes are quoted, and validate your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) function works, as it's name says, with html tag names (div, table, form, etc). In your case would be getElementsByTagName('table'). Instead you could use [getElementsByName.](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)

Answer (score 1):

To get the `table` element with attribute `myTab` from the element with id `register`, you can chain a [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) method to a [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) :

```js
table = document.getElementById('register').querySelectorAll('table[name=myTab]')[0];
console.log(table)
```

```html
<h1 align=center>Register with our portal</h1>

<FORM id="register" onsubmit="return checkForm();" METHOD="POST">

  <table name="myTab" border=0 align=center>
    <tr>
      <td> Username </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td><input name="username" class=textbox type=t ext required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Password </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td><input name="passwd" class=textbox type=p assword required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Confirm Password </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td><input name="c_password" class=textbox type=p assword required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> <input class=button type=s ubmit value=R egister> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</FORM>
```

Note that [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) get the elements from their name, not from their name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to access form elements. In your code you can access form elements using

```
var x = document.getElementById("register").elements;
```

This will give you all the elements in your form. However if you want to access first element you can use something like below code

```
 document.getElementById("register").elements[0].value // 0 is the index as per all the elements present in your form 'register'
```